# Проигрывание flv-файлов

Tags: android, java, flv

Можем ли мы проигрывать flv на андроиде в `VideoView/MediaPlayer`? Вариант с `WebView` не предлагать, т.к лично видел, допустим, взять многие плееры контактовского (моя цель аналогична), то они проигрывают видео явно не в `WebView`. Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: Вам нужно проигрывать flv или потоковую инфу, видео/музыку?

Если потоковые данные, то @Server предлагает правильный вариант. Ибо при чем здесь FLV? В ВК идет поток данных по TCP, любой плеер, поддерживающий его формат, может подцепить и проиграть.

Если же, вам нужен именно проигрыватель, который способен выполнять флеш-анимацию, то тут уже ничем не помочь пока, кроме WebView или совета @DroidAlex.

Answer (score 3):

Нативной поддержки flv в Андроиде точно нету: 
[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

А Вы уверены, что в Контакте .flv, а не .mp4, а если и так, почему Вы уверены, что не `WebView` и почему бы его не использовать?

П.С. Ни в коем случае не развожу полемику, самому тоже интересно.

Comment: Читал на хабре как выстаскивать URL с контакта. Там только flv. Декомпильнул прил (просмоторщик видео вконтакте) там был MediaPlayer правда как он работает с flv узнать не смог, декомпил же...

Comment: @AndroidDev, я вот задавал такой [вопрос](http://hashcode.ru/questions/11301/проигрыватель-flv-android) уже давненько, может, найдете себе что-то полезное.

Comment: Видел уже. Там про WebView не вариант

Comment: Пожалуйста, поделитесь решением, если найдете.

Comment: Вроде неплохо [написано](http://www.synesthesia.it/playing-flash-flv-videos-in-android-applications).

Comment: Тоже про WebView написано

Comment: А может, что более точно убедиться, удалить флеш плеер с телефона и посмотреть запуститься ли плеер ВКОНТАКТЕ ? Если не запуститься, значит все таки веб вье, а если запуститься хз :(

Comment: Я решил, проблему проигрывания flv, вещанием через RTSP.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, спустится на самый низ, используя Android NDK и написать свой контейнер для flv если это вообще возможно. Ну это жестчайшая жесть. На Хабре была статья, где человек эксперементировал с аудиоподсистемой в Android. Поищите, может пригодится.

Еще один вариант, найти библиотеку.

**UPD**

Третий вариант - конвертировать либо находу, либо заранее flv-файл в поддерживаемый платформой формат.